# close login form after entering correct username and pass

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I want to the login form be closed after entering correct use pass and show the main form

```
if (isValidateUser == true)
        {

            HomePage homepage = new HomePage();
            homepage.Show();

            this.Close();
        }
```

but after this code all of application is closed .
can you help me?

Comment: I think when you close the first form the application ends. You may want to load up homepage and launch your login from there as a model dialog box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

You start `HomePage` and on the `OnLoad()` method override show the login form

```
public partial class HomePage : Form
{
    public HomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        var dlg=new LoginForm();
        dlg.StartPosition=FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        if(dlg.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
        {
            userStatusLabel.Text=dlg.UserName;
        }
        else
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

The login form needs to expose the login information

```
public string UserName { get { return usrText.Text; } }
```

and the `[OK]` button have the `DialogResult` property set to `DialogResult.OK` and similarly with the `[Cancel]` button. And make sure the user cannot press ok until the password is valid.

[image: Login]
[image: HomePage]

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell too much, so I'll make some suppositions.

I suppose this is the code from `LoginForm`. I also suppose that you call `Application.Exit()` in the handler for the `Close` event for the form. That's what is closing your application. You should flag someone (like using a `bool` and setting it to `true` before calling `Close()`) that the form should just close and not call `Application.Exit()`.

Comment: my problem is when a validated user is identified instead of calling homepage and closing login form , all the application is closed.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close.aspx) on Form.Close Method

> When a form is closed, all resources created within the object are
>   closed and the form is disposed. You can prevent the closing of a form
>   at run time by handling the Closing event and setting the Cancel
>   property of the CancelEventArgs passed as a parameter to your event
>   handler. If the form you are closing is the startup form of your
>   application, your application ends.

You can use the Hide() method to hide the current form instead of closing it.

Comment: there is problem in Hide(), when you use it all the resources has been allocated and you can not release it